# Can't access WordPress page revisions via REST API

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have following code:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/index.js', [ 'jquery' ] );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'myScriptVars', [
        'root'  => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
    ] );
}
```

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: myScriptVars.root + 'wp/v2/pages/2/revisions/1',
    data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, _wpnonce: myScriptVars.nonce },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    },
});
```

But I am getting a 404 error in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing the X-WP-NONCE:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: myScriptVars.root + 'wp/v2/posts/1/revisions',
    data: { foo: 'bar', baz: 1, _wpnonce: myScriptVars.nonce },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function ( data ) {
        console.log( data );
    },
      headers: {
    'X-WP-Nonce': myScriptVars.nonce
    },
});
```